# LINQ entity from database view with MANY to MANY relation

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, linq-to-sql

i have a problem. I have a database view with many to many relation, it looks like this

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.PostAdditional.Description, dbo.PostAdditional.Summary,  dbo.PostAdditional.Title, dbo.Post.PostID, dbo.Post.Type, dbo.Tags.TagID, dbo.Tags.TagName, 
FROM dbo.Post 
INNER JOIN dbo.PostAdditional ON dbo.Post.PostID = dbo.PostAdditional.PostID 
INNER JOIN dbo.PostWithTags ON dbo.Post.EventID = dbo.PostWithTags.PostID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Tags ON dbo.PostWithTags.TagID = dbo.Tags.TagID
ORDER BY dbo.Post.StartDate, dbo.Post.PubDate
```

I want to use LINQ to SQL to work with it. When I normaly put this view in DBML designer, it creates an entity. But entity has proterty TagName as String, and I want it as array of tag names (or better List<>). When I take data from database, i get one copy of Post entity for evry single tag, but I want to get one Post entity with array of all tags associated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:
I changed this join from

```
INNER JOIN dbo.PostWithTags ON dbo.Post.EventID = dbo.PostWithTags.PostID
```

To

```
INNER JOIN dbo.PostWithTags ON dbo.Post.PostID = dbo.PostWithTags.PostID
```

And if I understand you right is this what you want?

```
var test=
    (
        from p in db.Post
        orderby p.StartDate,p.PubDate
        select new
        {
            p.PostID, 
            p.Type,
            Tags=
                (
                    from pa in db.PostAdditional
                    join pwt in db.PostWithTags 
                        on pa.PostID equals pwt.PostID
                    join t in db.Tags 
                        on pwt.TagID equals t.TagID
                    where p.PostID == pa.PostID
                    select new
                    {
                        pa.Description,
                        pa.Summary,
                        pa.Title,
                        t.TagID,
                        t.TagName
                    }
                )
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Where db is the databasecontext

Comment: Yeas, I want what you wrote as LINQ query, but as SQL view, and make LINQ entity from it.